# how can I preview an image before uploading it to a server in spring boot thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot

Please how do i preview an image before upload in spring boot thymeleaf. There are a lot of tutorials out there on how to upload images to server but not on previewing the image before uploading it to server

[image]

Comment: Methinks you'll have to upload it, then provide a preview/confirm type dialogue.

Comment: The point is am designing a registration system that users have to enter all their details, choose a profile picture before clicking on the register button.

Comment: Well either 1) this is a client side problem, i.e. no upload, in which case Thymeleaf is irrelevant because that's server side - you need to look at JS libraries or 2) you preemptively upload, in which cause it is a Thymeleaf problem. There is no 3.